# Get package name for a function in go language

Tags: go, package

I need to get the package name for a function in Go.
For example if `Println` is the input then the output must be `fmt`. If `StatusText` is the input then the output must be `net/http`.

What is the right method to achieve this?

Comment: You might be able to get better answers if you add information why you need this functionality. Have you checked http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc?

Comment: I need to get the documentation only for a function. But the thing is i know only the function name but not the package to which it belongs.

Comment: Give a try to `godoc -q Println | sed -n -e '/Functions/,$p' | head -n 2`

Answer (score 1):

From your comment it seems that you're looking for a command line tool like `godoc` but which instead of requiring something like `godoc net/http StatusText` you want to be able to just use `doc StatusText` and have it find `http.StatusText` for you (and possibly other `foo.StatusText` functions as well).

Rob Pike's [`doc`](https://godoc.org/robpike.io/cmd/doc) tool can do exactly that, it looks through all packages in your `GOPATH`. (Although it's output isn't just the package name as your original question asks for).

You can get and install `doc` with: `go install robpike.io/cmd/doc`

Or are you actually looking for a way of getting this information from within Go code rather than the command line?

Comment: Note that the doc tool will be part of the upcoming Go 1.5 release, so with a standard release you will be able to write "go doc Println".